# images are uploaded to folder but not to SQL database

Tags: php, mysql

I'm kind of a beginner here, I want to upload several images to SQL database and a folder, I am currently testing this on my local host, it uploads normally to my folder but does not upload to SQL database, any advice?

the HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<?php 
$conn = mysql_connect("localhost","root","")or die("could not connect"); 
mysql_selectdb("decorydata", $conn);
?>
<html lang="en">
 <head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Import data from Decory DB</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta name="title" content="Hemant Vishwakarma">
  <meta name="description" content="Import Excel File To MySql Database Using php">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
 </head>
 <body>    
<br><br>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
         <div class="col-md-12 text-center"><h1> All Decory images </h1>    </div>
<br>
            <div class="col-md-3 hidden-phone"></div>
            <div class="col-md-6" id="form-login">
                <form class="well" action="import-img.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                    <fieldset>
                        <legend>Import image file</legend>
                        <div class="control-group">
                            <div class="control-label">
                                <label>image File:</label>
                            </div>
                            <div class="controls form-group">
                                <input type="file" name="files[]" id="file" class="input-large form-control" multiple>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="control-group">
                            <div class="controls">
                            <button type="submit" id="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-flat btn-lg pull-right button-loading" data-loading-text="Loading...">Upload images</button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </fieldset>
                </form>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-3 hidden-phone"></div>
        </div>


        <table class="table table-bordered">
            <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>ID</th>
                        <th>name</th>
                        <th>type</th>

                    </tr> 
                  </thead>
            <?php
                $SQLSELECT = "SELECT * FROM images";
                $result_set =  mysql_query($SQLSELECT, $conn);
                while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result_set))
                {
                ?>
                    <tr>
                        <td><?php echo $row['ID']; ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $row['name']; ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $row['type']; ?></td>
                    </tr>
                <?php
                }
            ?>
        </table>
    </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

the PHP:

```
<?php

$conn = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "") or die("could not connect");
mysql_selectdb("decorydata", $conn);

$rd = rand();
if (isset($_FILES['files'])) {
$errors = array();
foreach ($_FILES['files']['tmp_name'] as $key => $tmp_name) {
    $file_name = $key . $rd . $_FILES['files']['name'][$key];
    $file_size = $_FILES['files']['size'][$key];
    $file_tmp = $_FILES['files']['tmp_name'][$key];
    $file_type = $_FILES['files']['type'][$key];
    if ($file_size > 2097152) {
        $errors[] = 'File size must be less than 2 MB';
    }
    $query = "INSERT INTO images (name,type) VALUES($file_name','$file_type',); ";
    $desired_dir = "uploadphotos";
    if (empty($errors) == true) {
        if (is_dir($desired_dir) == false) {
            mkdir("$desired_dir", 0700);  // Create directory if it does not exist
        }
        if (is_dir("$desired_dir/" . $file_name) == false) {


            $src = imagecreatefromjpeg($tmp_name);


            list($width, $height) = getimagesize($tmp_name);


            $newwidth = ($width / $height) * 150;
            $newheight = 150;
            $tmp = imagecreatetruecolor($newwidth, $newheight);

            imagecopyresampled($tmp, $src, 0, 0, 0, 0, $newwidth, $newheight, $width, $height);
            $rd = rand();

            $filename = "thumbphotos/" . $file_name;
            imagejpeg($tmp, $filename, 100);

            imagedestroy($src);

            move_uploaded_file($file_tmp, "$desired_dir/" . $file_name);
        } else {         // rename the file if another one exist
            $new_dir = "$desired_dir/" . $file_name . time();
            rename($file_tmp, $new_dir);
        }
        mysql_query($query);
    } else {
        print_r($errors);
    }
}
if (empty($error)) {
    echo " <div class='alert alert-success'>Your Photos Is Successfully Uploded.<a href='imagesupload.php'> Add new Photos</a></div>";
}
}
?>
```

What am I missing?

Comment: it's a typo `VALUES($file_name',` and `',);` <<< and checking for errors would have told you about it.

Comment: **WARNING**: If you're just learning PHP, please, do not use the [`mysql_query`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php) interface. It’s so awful and dangerous that it was removed in PHP 7. A replacement like [PDO is not hard to learn](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access/) and a guide like [PHP The Right Way](http://www.phptherightway.com/) explains best practices. Your user data is **not** [properly escaped](http://bobby-tables.com/php.html) and there are [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/) and can be exploited.

Comment: well thx alot :) , sorry im very tired from the long working hours and i slipped this typo

Answer (score 1):

Is there a big reason why you want to upload an image into a database? It is not efficient and it takes a toll in processing. You would have to deconstruct the image in order to insert it in the database. Then when you need to pull the image out to display you will have to reconstruct it. Also, having images in your database will make your database size grow dramatically  even with just a few rows in the table.
Best practice is to upload the image file in a folder which you already have working. Then just grab the name of the image file along with its extension and store that in the database. When you need to display the image just have the static path where you are storing the images and dynamically pull the name of the image you desire from the database.

Comment: thx for the advice but if you look closely to the php file this is exactly what i'm doing ,i am uploading the images to the folder "uploadedphotos" and just their name and type to the database , because once i need to display them then i just call them by their name from the folder and i'm done :)

Answer (score -1):

Its typo In the `$query` string. One `,` and `;` too many.

Please Use:

```
mysql_query($query) or die('Error: '.mysql_error());
```

This would of shown you the error.

Please Take A look into Mysqli instead of mysql.
http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php